# How to change bottom app bar navigation icon programmatically

Tags: android

I am making an Android application which has one activity and many fragments. The activity contains a bottom app bar and that bottom bar has a navigation icon in it. Like this:

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorbottomappbar"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_green_24dp">

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

This navigation menu icon will be shown in every fragment. However, in some fragments I want to change that navigation icon in the bottom app bar to back button/icon. How can I achieve this? Also, currently I handle the navigation icon click in the main activity. How can I handle the click in the case of the back icon? How will it know what the current fragment is and how can I determine which fragment the back icon leads to?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomappbar/BottomAppBar), you'll see that `BottomAppBar` extends from `Toolbar` and it has an inherited method called `setNavigationIcon(int res)`.

You can implement an interface that your main Activity implements like so:

```
interface FramentChangedListener {
     void onFragmentChanged(int type);
}
```

Your activity would do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FragmentChangedListener {
    // This will keep track of what is currently shown
    private int current = 0;

    @Override
    public void onFragmentChanged(int type) {
        if (type == FirstFragment.SOME_TYPE) {
            // Update the current fragment value, we're associating each fragment 
            // with an int value.
            current = type;

            bottomAppBar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.your_back_icon);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In your fragment you would do something like this:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentChangedListener listener;
    public static final int SOME_TYPE = 1;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceOf FragmentChangedListener) {
            // context in this case is your activity, which implements FragmentChangedListener
            listener = (FragmentChangedListener) context;

            // You can call the listener now
            listener.onFragmentChanged(SOME_TYPE);
        }
    }
}
```

In your Activity, add a listener to the BottomAppBar via `setNavigationOnClickListener` and whenever you receive the navigation icon event, you can check against the `current` value that we defined.